# Stream JasperPrint directly to PDF

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Is it possible to stream the result directly to a pdf file instead of creating the JasperPrint object first? My JasperPrint object can get really big and java.lang.OutOfMemoryError occurs...

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, reportparameter.getAll(), dataSource);
// dead end
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/Users/bla/Desktop/test/JasperReport.pdf"));
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, output);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I kind of found a solution... First you write the JasperPrint object to disk and then you can stream the content and create PDF via streams.
No memory problems anymore but you need to save the result first on the disk.

```
    OutputStream printOut = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/Users/bla/Desktop/test/jasperprint.jasperprint"));
    JasperFillManager.fillReportToStream(jasperReport, printOut, reportparameter.getAll(), dataSource);
    printOut.close();

    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/Users/bla/test/JasperReport.pdf"));
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Users/bla/Desktop/test/jasperprint.jasperprint")), output);
    output.close();
```

Comment: You can also take a look at report virtualizers http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/virtualizer/index.html